# Spring MVC error: WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm running into this error with the below code:

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

`HelloController.java`:

```
package com.xxx.hellocontroller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class HelloController extends AbstractController {

@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
    modelandview.addObject("welcomeMessage", "Welcome to Spring MVC");
    return modelandview;
}
}
```

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com /xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

`spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="HandlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

<bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.xxx.hellocontroller.HelloController" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

`HelloPage.jsp`:

```
<html>
<body>
   <h1>First Spring MVC Application Demo</h1>

    <h2>${welcomeMessage}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

`Console log`:

```
    usage: java org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina [ -config {pathname} ] [ -nonaming ]  { -help | start | stop }
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVC' did not find a matching property.
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Nov 3 2014 08:39:16 UTC
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         7.0.57.0
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            6.1
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_25-b18
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\g.v\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\g.v\Documents\MyDocs\tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\g.v\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\g.v\Documents\MyDocs\tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\g.v\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\g.v\Documents\MyDocs\tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\endorsed
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_51/lib/i386;c:\programdata\oracle\java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files (x86)\java\jre7\bin;c:\program files\tortoisesvn\bin;c:\program files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Users\g.v\Downloads\eclipse;;.
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 833 ms
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:48 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
    INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [394] milliseconds.
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 2544 ms
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher'
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher': initialization started
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:51 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Aug 24 13:24:51 ADT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:51 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
    INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome.html] onto handler '/welcome.html'
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher': initialization completed in 547 ms
    Aug 24, 2015 1:24:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
    WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

Comment: Post full stack trace.

Comment: @BranislavLazic, I have added the console log

Answer (score 0):

you only accepted request from absolute path '/'. include this in your servlet mapping. It might solve your problem

```xml
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: oh! pretty sad... here is a guid that can help you tho http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/